# How to remove borders from cells in a range in Excel using VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, border, vba

**Aim to Achieve:**
To get rid of borders if any in the cells of range.

I have :

```
Dim range As Excel.Range = sheet.Range("A2:K100")
For Each cell In range
    // Some cells in the Range has borders
    // How to remove borders from cells in the range
Next cell
```

**Please help.. !**

I am new to Vb.net !

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
range.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
range.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
range.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
range.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
range.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
range.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
```

Removes the borders around the cells and between cells (via `xlInsideHorizontal` and `xlInsideVertical`). If you expect diagonal borders, include `xlDiagonalDown` and `xlDiagonalUp`.

Okay, the above code was very verbose. The following should do it too:

```
For Each border in range.Borders
    border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
Next
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.borders.aspx

**EDIT:**

While looking over the MSDN page, I'm wondering if this one liner could do it too:

```
range.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
```

Comment: It would be very slow if the range.. is too big.. 
So, can it do for the whole range at once ?

Comment: It should be very fast since you're not iterating over every cell like in your sample. Did you try it?

Comment: I suppose its similar like we are iterating over the border of each cell .. I mean you solution seems good, but isn't there an direct method for the whole range ?
I think there must be one ?

Comment: Wait.. the one liner.. is what I was looking for..
**GREAT !! THANX !!**

Comment: The one-liner works for me in Excel 2007 on Windows 7 :)

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily repetitive, even the one-liner is more than needed. You can just get away with `Range("A2:K100").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone`, there is no need to over-egg this.

Answer (score 12):

`Range("A2:K100").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone`

Comment: This is the correct answer. The others are unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 5):

why are all the answers so convoluted?

for the entire sheet use...

```
With .Cells
       .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
End With
```

for a range just replace .Cells as appropriate

Comment: 2020 and this was the answer i am looking for..  Thank you.

Comment: or simply `Cells.Borders.LineStyle=xlLineStyleNone` to clear all borders on the active worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Check [NamedRange.BorderAround Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.borderaround.aspx) .

```
Dim range As Excel.Range = sheet.Range("A2:K100")
range.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, missing)
```

cheers and good luck!

Comment: It manages the borders around the range and not inside the range. I am modifying the question to be clear.