# Removing the border lines in a worksheet when code has been run

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that successfully looks into an external file and copy/pastes the rows that contain that particular condition into the current workbook. For example I am searching for `Singapore` in the external workbook called Active master project file and copy all the rows containing `Singapore` to the current workbook that is open.

A problem that occurs is that when I run the same code twice, a border line will exist on the last row of the worksheet. For example when I run the code, it will copy paste the information containing `Singapore` to the current worksheet called "New Upcoming Projects":

[image]

However, when I run the code again it will create a border line on each column such as the image shown below:

[image]

And the code that I have for now is:

```
Sub UpdateNewUpcomingProj()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long '<~~ Not Integer. Might give you error in higher versions of excel
    Dim strSearch As String

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("U:\Active Master Project.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("New Upcoming Projects")

    strSearch = "Singapore"
    With ws1

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> I am assuming that the names are in Col A
        '~~> if not then change A below to whatever column letter
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '~~> Destination File
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("New Upcoming Projects")
     With ws2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 2
        End If

       copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
      .Rows.RemoveDuplicates Array(2), xlNo

    End With
End Sub
```

Is there any improvement or additional codes that I have to add in so that the border line would disappear?

Comment: Hi haven't tried your code and so don't know *why* you're getting a border.  But can't you just remove the border after you copy the range?  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974965/how-to-remove-borders-from-cells-in-a-range-in-excel-using-vb-net - Ian

Comment: I could remove the border but the user will find it troublesome having to always delete the border every time he or she runs the code. That is why i am wondering if there is any way i could remove the border to prevent from regularly delete the border when the code is played @EyePeaSea

Comment: Last line of code to remove borders, `Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone`

Comment: @nabilah - Sorry for the confusion - the link I provided (and the answer also given by Katz and Davesexcel) relate to adding code to your existing VBA - so the user doesn't have to do anything.

Comment: Alright thank you! I did take a look at it :) @EyePeaSea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this formatting is coming from the source worksheet.  If so, you could `PasteSpecial` to just paste values, keeping the destination formatting.  To do so, simply replace

```
copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
```

with

```
copyFrom.Copy
.Rows(lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
```

If you do need some formatting from the source sheet, you can use `xlPasteAllExceptBorders` instead of `xlPasteValues`.

Answer (score 4):

As EyePeaSea said you can remove the border by vba code, e.g.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XY").Range("A1", "Z99").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
```

In your case the code should be (untested)

```
copyFrom.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
```

after you copied the row

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Paste Special, this will paste to the first empty cell in column A

```
copyfrom.Copy
ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this line after removing the duplicates

```
.UsedRange.Offset(lRow).Borders.Value = 0
```

This will remove any borders from the inserted rows

p.s.: I still dont understand where these borders came from, most probably from the original worksheet.. :)

Comment: I also have no idea where the border come from too. Thank you! But the Code will also remove the border for my column headers too

Comment: @nabilah is that the only place where you have a border in the destination sheet?

Comment: Nope. Every Sheet there is a border for my column headers. And the code that you gave i use it for other worksheet and the result is the same. Still produce the border line on the last row

Comment: ok, plz try the edited version.. it will remove borders from the point the rows where added.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the code,
please add a new line to format paint of the 3rd row.

So basically before the last two lines
    wb1.Select ' please make sure you select the correct one wb1 or wb2 here and try again
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("4:10000").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    end with
    end sub 'This is the last line of your code

Comment: Hi i did try your code but it doesnt seem to work. The border is still there